# How to retrieve and create data from model via DJANGO REST API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am new to Django and Django Rest Framework so I need some help.

I want to receive time data from my model in Django. If there is no time stored for a particular user, it should create it, save it in my model and return that time data. I am also using Simple-JWT for token authentication which means that no one can access the database without a valid token.

This is my code so far:

**models.py:**

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    emp= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def get_time(request):
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        tk = request.GET.get('token') #token stored in LocalStorage
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tk}
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_api/'
        response = requests.get(url, headers)
        if response:
            user_id = User.objects.get(username=request.GET.get('username')).pk
            user = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
            if not Mymodel.objects.filter(emp=user).exists():
                current_time = timezone.now()
                create_time = Mymodel.objects.create(emp=user, time=current_time)
                data = create_time.time
        return HttpResponse(data)

class MyAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  #need to pass in JWT token in order to access the model.
    serializer = MySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = User.objects.get(username=request.GET.get('username')).pk
        user = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
        user_data = Mymodel.objects.all()
        queryset = user_data.filter(id=user_id)
        return queryset
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ('time')
```

I just want to read from my table and check whether if time is present for a user. If not, it should create time within the model. But, where am I going wrong? Did I pass in the Bearer token right and isn't the API structure correct? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not best practice to use django method based and class based view together and in your model just and auto_now=True

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    emp= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

it will be automatically filled when instance created and you don't need to do this:

```
create_time = Mymodel.objects.create(emp=user, time=current_time)
```